# Pyplot Histogram fills all data into the first bin

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

So I've read a csv file into a dataframe, and then into an array. I've taken the 2nd column of the array into another array called, 'prices' and I want to put that into a histogram.

But the output I'm getting is (see attached image), even though all the prices range from 1 to 96840522.

Initially I was trying to build the histogram without having to subset the column I want, but that didn't work either...

Can anyone help please?

```
df = pd.read_csv(path+file, header=None, names=field_names)
data_array = df.values

prices = data_array[:,1]

plt.hist(prices, bins=10)
plt.show
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqQU7.png]

Comment: You'll need to create a MCVE if you want more help with this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. My guess is that the other bins are simply too short to see. `hist` returns the bins and counts. You should inspect those.

Comment: @PaulH you were right, the other bins were too small to see!